# ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is the dataset Im using-

```
X_train = X_train_norm.reshape(12279,25,1)
y_train= y_train.reshape(12279,8,1)
X_test = X_test_norm.reshape(6049,25,1)
y_test=y_test.reshape(6049,8,1)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)


(12279, 25, 1)
(12279, 8, 1)
(6049, 25, 1)
(6049, 8, 1)
```

The model-

```
n_outputs = 8
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=200, kernel_size=4, strides=3,activation='relu', input_shape=(25,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv1D(filters=200, kernel_size=5, strides=1,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))

model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))

model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))



model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])#,f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
print(model.summary())

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,patience=10)
# fit network
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_split=0.1,epochs=epoch_number, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1,callbacks=[es])
    # evaluate model
#loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall = 
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
print(loss,accuracy)#,f1_score,precision,recall)
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test,batch_size=32,verbose=1)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
```

I'm getting this error-

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,8]
```

Im doing multiclass classification using 1d CNN. Hence I have reshaped my Data to 3d array to give to 1d CNN

Answer (score 0):

You need to squeeze the label dataset shape before feeding it to the model training.

```
y_train = tf.squeeze(y_train, axis=-1)
y_test = tf.squeeze(y_test, axis=-1)
```